# Not able to view "Process Watcher" window in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have isntalled pgAdmin 4 and i am trying to import the csv file into a table.I have followed all the steps mentioned in the document.
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/dev/import_export_data.html

Once I click on OK button at the end of the importing process. I don't get any message (either success not error) and also I am not able to see the "Process Watcher" window.

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to see any error/success messages?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in pgAdmin4 v1.2 for this, It is fixed in version 1.3 and it will release may be in next week, once it released upgrade your pgAdmin4 and try again.

Comment: In some version of PgAdmin 4 3.x it worked and i saw the process watcher/progress dialog, but then suddenly in a later version of 3.x it didn't work anymore. I just saw the backup file size changing and then when it didn't i knew the backup was complete.

Now i installed PgAdmin 4 4.1 and it is still not working. Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug and still not fixed, version 2.0 being the latest one.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.